# How can I integrate react-native-router-flux with Relay

Tags: navigation, react-native, router, relay

Should I wrapped all my routes in a RootContainer or Relay, or should I wrap only the Scenes that uses Relay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an issue https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/437

Implementation example https://github.com/r0b1n/rnrf-relay-example